# What is Type & TypeToken?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, typetoken

I have the following method in my project

```
 public void execute(final int apiId, final ResponseHandler handler, final Type type)
```

and the type is determined using TypeToken as follows

```
final Type serviceErrorType = new TypeToken<>() {
    }.getType();
```

I went through this [link](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) here but couldn't understand completely about `Type` and `TypeToken`

Can anyone please share a link or help understand these two concepts?

Comment: `TypeToken` is somewhat description of a `Type`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

From the [link](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) you provided:

> Forces clients to create a subclass of this class which enables retrieval the type information even at runtime.

Let's speak with example.

Assume you want to parse a JSON to Java class with [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library.
Now, you have to specifically tell Gson, that:

> I want this JSON to be translated to a **List** of **User** objects

How would you tell that to Gson? If it was only `User`, you could tell `User.class`. But it isn't possible to say `List<User>.class`

```
new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<User>>(){}.getType())
```

But now you can specify precisely that Gson should convert it to a `List of Users`.

Should quote explanation from docs:

> Represents a generic type `T`. Java doesn't yet provide a way to represent generic types, so this class does.

Have a look at [this blog post](http://helw.net/2017/11/09/runtime-generics-in-an-erasure-world/) for more details on the topic.

Comment: probably `new TypeToken<List<User>>(){}.getType()`