# How to define a generic List of types in java?

Tags: java, generics

I have implemented a java method with the following signature:

```
public <T> T getItemValue(String itemName, Class<T> itemType)  {
...
}
```

This allows a client to call the method in the following way to get for example a value of the type String or Integer:

```
String s = itemCol.getItemValue("_name", String.class);
int i = itemCol.getItemValue("_count", Integer.class);
```

This kind of method signature is also used by the [Config interface](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-config/blob/master/api/src/main/java/org/eclipse/microprofile/config/Config.java#L90) of the new microprofile Config 1.3 API.

My question is how - or if - I can call the method with a Type of List of Types like `List<String>` to get for example a List of String objects. 
I was not able to formulate the client call. I tried something like this:

```
List<String> list = itemCol.getItemValue("_count", List<String.class>);
```

but this seems not to be the correct syntax.

**EDITED:**

As a result of the responses below I decided to add a separate method to get a List of a specific type.

```
public <T> List<T> getItemValueList(String itemName, Class<T> itemType) {
        ...
}
```

With this additional method signature a client can decide weather to get a single value or a list of a specific type.

Comment: `List<String>.class` does not work because of type erasure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens

Comment: This is correct, just with a warning. Java does not have ```List<String>.class```, only ```List.class```, so there is an unsafe type conversion warning.

Comment: Would it than be a solution to add a second method like this `public <T> List<T> getItemValueList(String itemName, Class<T> itemType)` which allows the client to call like this `List<String> slist = itemCol.getItemValueList("txtname", String.class);` ? Do you find this solution better?

Comment: If you have control over the data, you may want to use arrays instead of Lists.  `String[].class` is completely valid and will not generate any warnings.

Comment: As the List interface is important to the client code, I now added a separate method. See my edited question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Type Parameters are erased, they don't exist at runtime. There is no such thing as `List<String>` at runtime, there is only `List`.

So, the correct way to express a reflective proxy for `List<String>` is … you can't. You can only express a reflective proxy for `List`, the same way you do for any other class: `List.class`.

Comment: But how would the client code than look like? `List<String> list = itemCol.getItemValue("_count", List.class)` ?? - How can my implementation know that the returned list should contain only String elements?

Comment: It can't. The type is erased. It doesn't exist at runtime. That's what "type erasure" means. The type is gone.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I added a new separate method. See my edited question.

Answer (score 4):

Not with `List<String.class>`, no. You need to use a [TypeToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117731/what-is-type-typetoken) to get that sort of generic information. You also need to change your code to work with `Type` instead of `Class`.